# Curl To Variable Not Working

Tags: bash, curl

I am attempting to grab a specific field from a curl request. It works perfectly fine via the shell, but as soon as I try to assign a variable it stops working.

This is the stand-alone command.

```
curl --silent 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=MNC131&y=0' | grep -E '  <title>' | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}'
```

This is the small bit from the script. It echos a blank variable.

```
weatheralert=$(curl --silent 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=MNC131&y=0' | grep -E '  <title>' | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}')
echo "Current Weather Alert: $weatheralert"
```

Comment: it fails to work on shell also.

Comment: `$ curl --silent 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=MNC131&y=0' | grep -E '  <title>' | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}'

There are no active watches, warnings or advisories`

Works for me...

Comment: Change `'  <title>'` to `'<title>'`.

Comment: @user3439894 The tab is required to grab the proper <title>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is a `tab` character exists before `<title>` tag not 3 or 4 whitespace. So copy paste a tab character or use `grep -P '\t<title>'` command.

```
$ weatheralert=$(curl --silent 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=MNC131&y=0' | grep -P '\t<title>'|awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}')
$ echo "Current Weather Alert: $weatheralert"
Current Weather Alert: There are no active watches, warnings or advisories
```